# jQuery, не обрабатывается код для второго div с таким же ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

Суть задачи: открывать модальное окошко, подставляя данные из атрибута data элемента, по которому кликаем.

Пытаюсь сделать как то так:

```
$('#op').on('click',function(){



        console.log(this);
        var el = this;
        console.log($(el).attr('data'));
        var data = $(el).attr('data');
        $('#meta').html(data);
        console.log('Meta '+data);
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
```

Отрабатывает стабильно только для первого элемента с ID = op. Для каждого последующего - просто игнорируется.

Два вопроса, почему и как исправить?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: id должен быть уникальный для каждого элемента на странице.

Comment: И поделом! *(5 символов нужно...)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Согласно W3C спецификации это не валидно.

Попробуйте всем элементам заменить ID на классы, или попробуйте изменить селектор на следующий:

```
$('[id="op"]');
```